# How to upload Audio (Mp3) to Server Using Retrofit2 Android

Tags: php, android, retrofit

How to upload an audio file by retrofit?

I brought some of the classes and code I wrote, but I did not respond to these codes

Interface:

```
 @Multipart
    @POST("comments")
    Call<Wallet> setComent(@Part("voice") RequestBody song, @Part("api_token") String api_token, @Part("product") String product, @Part("body") String body);
```

Class :

```
 AudioSavePathInDevice =
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" +
                        "NAME" + "AudioRecording.mp3";


    File file = new File(AudioSavePathInDevice );

                    //creating request body for file
                    RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("audio/*"), file);

                    MyInterFace myInterFace = MyServices.createService(MyInterFace.class);
                    Call<Wallet> calling = myInterFace.setComent
                            (requestFile,new AppStore(getContext()).LoadMyShereKES(AppStore.Keys_TOKEN),AppStore.ID_BACHGROUD,Ediet.getText().toString());

                    calling.enqueue(new Callback<Wallet>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse( Call<Wallet> call,  Response<Wallet> response)
                        {
                            appStore.CloseDilag();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<Wallet> call, Throwable t)
                        {

                            appStore.CloseDilag();
                        }
                    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All files, whether audio, video, images... are basically the same for retrofit. They are just files. The interface is annotated with `@MultiPart.Part` just like any other file.
check [this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server) link for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Instead if using **RequestBody**, you should use "**MultipartBody**"
eg.

```
val file = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("audio", audioFile.name, audioFile.asRequestBody("audio/*".toMediaTypeOrNull()))
```